# check decimal or point Java

Tags: arrays, calculator

i am working on a calculator project.
i am using a method to separate the char and numeric values.
but i am getting problem on when i have a decimal value, because result shown 0 when decimal value runs.
here is the code.

```js
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> operators = new ArrayList<>();
..................

void testing() {

    String userInput = "234+234+234";
    /* ignore the line above its just for understanding */
    /*the above works fine but if we change it to below its dont work.*/
    String userInput = "234+2.3+4.2";
  /*  The both lines above are just for understanding actually i am getting text from edittext*/
    String userInput = currentcalc.getText().toString();
    for (char c : userInput.toCharArray()) {
     if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            s1 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
            numbers.add(s1);
            operators.add(c);
            handler++;
            s2 = "";
            s1 = 0;
     } else {
            s = Character.toString(c);
            s2 += s;
        }
    }
    result();
}
```

> 

result = 0.0

s and s2 are strings and s1 is double. and in my code if c is not a digit it is saving value of operator like +,- etc and else it is saving value of digits and other things. i want to know that why "." is not being save via this code and why result is showing 0.0

the result(); code is here below

```js
void result() {

  double total4 = 0;
  s1 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
  numbers.add(s1);
  if (handler < 1) {
   total4 = Double.parseDouble(currentcalc.getText().toString());
  } else {
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < handler; i++) {

    switch (operators.get(i)) {
    case '/':

     total3 = numbers.get(i) / numbers.get(i + 1);
     total4 = total3;
     numbers.remove(i + 1);
     numbers.set(i, total4);
     operators.remove(i);
     handler--;
     i--;
     break;
    }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < handler; i++) {
    switch (operators.get(i)) {
    case '*':

     total3 = numbers.get(i) * numbers.get(i + 1);
     total4 = total3;
     numbers.remove(i + 1);
     numbers.set(i, total4);
     operators.remove(i);
     handler--;
     i--;
     break;
    }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < handler; i++) {
    switch (operators.get(i)) {
    case '+':

     total3 = numbers.get(i) + numbers.get(i + 1);
     total4 = total3;
     numbers.remove(i + 1);
     numbers.set(i, total4);
     operators.remove(i);
     break;
    case '-':

     total3 = numbers.get(i) - numbers.get(i + 1);
     total4 = total3;
     numbers.remove(i + 1);
     numbers.set(i, total4);
     operators.remove(i);

     break;
    }
    handler--;
    i--;
   }
  }
  et1.setText(Double.toString(total4));
  resettext = 1;
 }
```

Comment: What does your code do when it tries to execute the "." operatator?  At the moment, you're treating "." as an operator, just like "+".

Comment: Use javascript engine available in Java to eval the expression.

Comment: s and s2 are strings and s1 is double. and in my code if c is not a digit it is saving value of operator like +,- etc and else it is saving value of digits and other things. i want to know that why "." is not being save via this code and why result is showing 0.0

Comment: Your code looks confusing and wrong. You need a few data structures to do this correctly, either 2 Stacks or a Stack and Queue and turn the equation into postfix. 1 + 2 -> 1 2 +.

Comment: What language is this really?  You didn't use any language tag, and your markdown says javascript, but I don't think that code is javascript...

Comment: it is java how to put it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your `result()` method, `total4` is set to 0.0 at the beginning, and no code ever changes it when the "." operator is encountered.

The bug is that you are treating "." as an operator. Have special code in your parsing loop to treat it as part of the number. You need to change the line `if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {`, and handle the maths logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to implement any specific algorithm then you can use:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");        
Object result = engine.eval("3+4");
```

Otherwise you may want to look at the following:
[Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: wajahat bro i really dont understand your above code can you explain in easy way?

Comment: eval function in JS can evaluate strings which are mathematical expressions. Java can load the JS engine and use the eval function.

Comment: He's saying, don't re-implement a calculator, since there's one provided in the JavaScript engine. This is valid, but I think not helpful, since you are learning java and not simply looking to leverage JS.

Comment: Yea, thats what I said, if you are only using it as a part of bigger program then you can use JS engine.

Comment: it is java how to put it in java?